# Error configuracion single sign on CAS Server

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, autenticación, filtro

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicacion de java la cual redirecciona a otras aplicaciones para lo cual utiliza cas server 5.3 para autenficar los usuarios, el problema viene al momento de yo tratar de redireccionar a las aplicaciones pues la sesion se guarda pero solo para esa aplicacion y las demas requieren ser validadas independientemente de si estoy o no logeado en las otras.

El problema es que yo acceso a la primera aplicacion digamos aplicacion A y paso por el login del cas y me genera un ticket pero al momento de pasar de la aplicacion A a la aplicacion B me pide pasar por el login por segunda vez y me genera un segundo ticket, creo que mi error podria estar en los filtros dentro del web.xml pero no encuentro una respuesta que me ayude.

Estos son los filtros que tengo dentro del web.xml en cada una de las aplicaciones

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>https://cas.midominio.com:8445/cas/logout</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>https://cas.midominio.com:8445/cas</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://dev.midominio.com:8445</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://cas.midominio.com:8445/cas/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://dev.midominio.com:8445</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Error Redirect Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.ErrorRedirectFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>java.lang.Exception</param-name>
        <param-value>/error.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>defaultErrorRedirectPage</param-name>
        <param-value>/defaulterror.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Error Redirect Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```